# How to enable CUDA 7.0+ per-thread default stream in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, cuda

I followed the method provided in [GPU Pro Tip: CUDA 7 Streams Simplify Concurrency](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/) and tested it in VS2013 with CUDA 7.5. While the multi-stream example worked, the multi-threading one did not give the expected result. The code is as below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

#define CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM

#include "cuda.h"

const int N = 1 << 20;

__global__ void kernel(float *x, int n)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    for (int i = tid; i < n; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
        x[i] = sqrt(pow(3.14159, i));
    }
}

void *launch_kernel(void *dummy)
{
    float *data;
    cudaMalloc(&data, N * sizeof(float));

    kernel << <1, 64 >> >(data, N);

    cudaStreamSynchronize(0);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    const int num_threads = 8;

    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, launch_kernel, 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating threadn");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining threadn");
            return 2;
        }
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to add the macro CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM to CUDA C/C++->Host->Preprocessor Definitions, but the result was the same. The timeline generated by the Profiler is as below:
[image]

Do you have any idea on what happened here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting a posix threads implementation for windows?

Comment: @talomies From [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/), and it includes x64 binaries. Moreover, I also tried to use std::thread, but the results was the same.

Comment: Did you follow the compilation notes at the bottom of the article you linked to? Especially the --default-stream option?

Comment: @talonmies Yes, I did. I also tried the command line option. Same result. But as indicated in the programming guide, either the macro or the command line option should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updates:** the concurrency may happen when I added a "cudaFree" as shown below. Is it because of the lack of synchronization?

```
void *launch_kernel(void *dummy)
{
    float *data;
    cudaMalloc(&data, N * sizeof(float));

    kernel << <1, 64 >> >(data, N);
    cudaFree(data); // Concurrency may happen when I add this line
    cudaStreamSynchronize(0);

    return NULL;
}
```

with the compilation like:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_30  --default-stream per-thread -lpthreadVC2 kernel.cu -o kernel.exe
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted works for me as you would expect:

[image]

when compiled and run on a Linux system with CUDA 7.0 like so:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30  --default-stream per-thread -o thread.out thread.cu
```

From that I can only assume that either you have a platform specific issue, or your build method is incorrect (note that `--default-stream per-thread` must be specified for every translation unit in the build).

Comment: I've tried the compilation through command line, but also not work. I think it might owe to the OS's specific issue. But thank you all the same!